# When one and when two asterixes (indirection operators) when passing arguments to functions in C

Tags: c, malloc

I will be thankful for a very simple explanation why in the examples below I pass the pointer to the object using sometimes one and sometimes two asterixes (indirection operators). 
In both examples I dedicate memory to the variable / object in the external function, not in main. Can both examples be changed so they work with one/two asterixes when passing arguments? I tried I failed to do so. One example only works as it is, the other as it is. Cannot modify them. 
So can I pass a pointer to a structure to the external function with two indirection operators and allocate memory there for this structure?

And one more question, if the fuction returns something to main, does it make a copy of its argument, allocates new memory and returns the copy to main? Is the only way not to allocate new memory to variables to use functions returning nothing to main (void function(...))?

Two asterixes (indirection operators) in this example:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void funkcja(char ** w){ //adres adresu znaku
  char bufor[256];
  scanf("%s", bufor);
  int l;
  l=strlen(bufor); //pamiętać, że nie liczy 0 na końcu
  *w=(char*)malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char));
  if(*w==0) exit(1);  
  strcpy(*w,bufor); 
}


int main(){
  char * twsk[5];
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    funkcja(&twsk[i]); //adres i-tego elementu tej tablicy ktorym jest wsk
  }

  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%s\n",twsk[i]);
  } 
 return 0;
}
```

One asterix (indirection operator) here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Diament{
  float **kamienie; //tablica brylantów i kolczykow
  int count;
}diamenty;

diamenty * WprowadzanieCenBrylantow(diamenty * oferta);
void ObliczCeny(diamenty * oferta);
int Informacja(diamenty * oferta);
void Pokaz(diamenty * oferta);

int main(){
    diamenty * oferta;
    oferta = WprowadzanieCenBrylantow(oferta);
    Pokaz(oferta);
    ObliczCeny(oferta);
    /*Pokaz(oferta);*/
    Informacja(oferta);
    return 0;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

diamenty * WprowadzanieCenBrylantow(diamenty * oferta){
   int count=0;
   int i;
   printf("Podaj ilosc brylantów jakie chcesz wpisać -> ");
   scanf( "%d", &count );
   oferta = malloc(sizeof(diamenty)); //alokacja pamięci na całą strukturę
   oferta->kamienie = malloc(sizeof(float*)*count); //alokacja pamięci na tablicę cen, na odpowiednią liczbę wierszy
   for(i=1;i<count+1;i++){
      oferta->kamienie[i]=malloc(sizeof(float)*(count-i+1)); //alokacja pamięci na daną tablicę dodatkowy element na cenę kamienia, na kolumny
   }
   oferta->count=count;
   printf("Podaj ceny diamentów \n");
   for(i=1;i<count+1;i++){
      printf("Diament numer %d podaj jego cenę -> ",i);
      scanf("%f", &oferta->kamienie[i][0]); //kolumna 0 zawiera ceny pojedynczych brylantów i je tu wpisuję
      printf("Wpisana cena to -> %f \n", oferta->kamienie[i][0]);
    }
   return oferta;
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

void ObliczCeny(diamenty * oferta){
  int liczba = oferta->count;
  int i,j;
  for(i=1;i<liczba+1;i++){  //przesuwam się po numerach wszystkich kamieni
    for(j=1;j<liczba-i+1;j++){  //przesuwam się jeszcze raz po kamieniach ale tylko tyle aby dostać macierz trójkątną
        oferta->kamienie[i][j]=oferta->kamienie[i][0]+oferta->kamienie[liczba-j+1][0];
        /*printf("Kombinacja diament %d i diament %d , czyli kamienie[%d][%d] -> łączna cena wynosi %f\n", i, (oferta->count-j+1), i, j, (oferta->kamienie[i][j])); */
    }
  }
}


//***********************************************************
void Pokaz(diamenty * oferta){
   int i,j;
   int liczba=oferta->count;
   printf("\n");
   /*for(i=1;i<liczba+1;i++){
     printf("Cena wynosi -> %f \n", oferta->kamienie[i][0]);
   } */
   for (i=1;i<liczba+1;i++){
      for(j=1;j<liczba-i+1;j++){
          if(j==1){printf("Cena brylantu %d wynosi -> %f \n", i, oferta->kamienie[i][0]);}
          printf("%d %d %f \n -> ", i, liczba-j+1, oferta-> kamienie[i][liczba-j+1]);
      }
   }
}

//***********************************************************

int Informacja(diamenty * oferta){
   int kamien1, kamien2, temp;
   int liczba=oferta->count;
   char odpowiedz[256];
   do{
       printf("Podaj numery brylantów, które mają stworzyć kolczyki. \n Na początek podaj numer diamentu numer 1 -> ");
       scanf("%d",&kamien1);
       printf("Teraz podaj numer drugiego brylantu -> ");
       scanf("%d",&kamien2);
       if (kamien1>kamien2){
          temp=kamien1;
          kamien1=kamien2;
          kamien2=temp;}
       if (kamien1==kamien2) {printf("Nie można kupić dwa razy takiego samego kamienia\n"); return 0;}
       if (kamien1<=0 ||kamien2<=0) return 0;
       if(kamien1<=liczba && kamien2<=liczba)
           printf("Cena: %f\n",oferta->kamienie[kamien1][oferta->count-kamien2+1]);
       printf("Czy chcesz sprawdzić ceny innej pary kolczyków? Wpisz T albo N");
       scanf("%s", odpowiedz);
       }while((strcmp(odpowiedz,"N")!=0)&&(strcmp(odpowiedz,"n")!=0));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `asterix`? Oh no, that's called a indirection operator. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: You should read a good C programming book. Because if you don't understand much about pointers, explaining them to you is *not* simple.

Comment: I am reading Stephen Prata book but this is not something that appears first in the programming book. I expected a picture depicting memory and how this addressing works on the memory. For the time being, I explain it to myself in the following way. Array of strings is an array of pointers. So if I want to pass it, I have to create a pointer to this array, but since this array is an array of pointers, I end up with a pointer to the pointers. Hence, two indirection operators. When I deal with the structure, I have already a pointer to it and I just pass it.

Answer (score 0):

** is a pointer to a pointer. It's used here because the function that takes it as an argument needs to change the pointer itself, not what it is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

**First Case**: you pass a pointer to pointer, since you pass the address of the pointer it will be modified inside the function, and you can reassing the pointer inside the function as in

```
*w = (char*)malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char))
```

in this case after the function returns, the `one star` pointer in your main function now points to newly allocated (and in this case initialized) memory.

**Second Case**: you just pass a pointer, although you can modify the content of the memory it points to, if you assign it to a different pointer, the effect will be local to the function.

**Note**: it is discouraged to cast the result of `malloc` in the c language, it's the most popular c question in SO, look it up.

Comment: Casting `malloc()` seems to be deprecated on this site and, while I agree it is pointless, I have been casting around to see why many, many people continue to do it. And an answer is: they read K&R and do what it says. Both the original K&R and the 2nd edition always cast the result from `malloc()`. By the same token, it is pointless multiplying the length by `sizeof(char)` as l is defined as being the number of bytes (of whatever length they locally are).